# Google+ oauth / 0auth API: How can I prevent redirection by google-signin2 button?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-signin, google-plus-signin

I am just learning the basics of Google´s API 0auth authentication sign-in system.

I'm using this tutorial found on [CodexWorld](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s6pwjKGdEU8). Although this one worked out, it uses an ugly picture instead of a "real" google sign-in button (from the *g-signin2* class), and that´s something I personally just can´t get over.

I tried replaced the picture with that button and added the required metas to work with it. But now it opened 2 windows, not only 1 through the php.
How can i prevent the second window, opened by the `g-signin2`-button, from opening?

Thanks for all your help!
VicStudio

---

Here´s the modified code by me. Notice how I replaced the picture button with a real `google-signin2` button and added the required metas.

```html
<?php
//Include GP config file && User class
include_once 'gpConfig.php';
include_once 'classuser.php';

if(isset($_GET['code'])){
    $gClient->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['token'] = $gClient->getAccessToken();
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirectURL, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
    $gClient->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

if ($gClient->getAccessToken()) {
    //Get user profile data from google
    $gpUserProfile = $google_oauthV2->userinfo->get();
    
    //Initialize User class
    $user = new User();
    
    //Insert or update user data to the database
    $gpUserData = array(
        'oauth_provider'=> 'google',
        'oauth_uid'     => $gpUserProfile['id'],
        'email'         => $gpUserProfile['email'],
        'link'          => $gpUserProfile['link']
    );
    $userData = $user->checkUser($gpUserData);
    
    //Storing user data into session
    $_SESSION['userData'] = $userData;
    
    //Render facebook profile data
    if(!empty($userData)){
        $output = '<h1>Google+ Profile Details </h1>';
        $output .= '<br/>Google ID : ' . $userData['oauth_uid'];
        $output .= '<br/>Email : ' . $userData['email'];
        $output .= '<br/>Logged in with : Google';
        $output .= '<br/><a href="'.$userData['link'].'" target="_blank">Click to Visit Google+ Page</a>';
        $output .= '<br/>Logout from <a href="logout.php">Google</a>'; 
    }else{
        $output = '<h3 style="color:red">Some problem occurred, please try again.</h3>';
    }
} else {
    //New, modified code:

    $authUrl = $gClient->createAuthUrl();
    $authUrl = filter_var($authUrl, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
    $output = "<div class='g-signin2' data-onsuccess='onSignIn' id='glog'></div> <script>document.getElementById('glog').onclick = function () { window.location.href = '".$authUrl."'; } </script>";
    
    //Original Code:

    // $authUrl = $gClient->createAuthUrl();
    // $output = '<a href="'.filter_var($authUrl, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL).'"><img src="images/glogin.png" alt=""/></a>';
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
        <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="246194741577-gajd75di0cam2j9u4q69l9trvg88hqkc.apps.googleusercontent.com">
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div><?php echo $output; ?></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you may want to read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.   Also please include enough code for us to see what you are doing.   There is a difference between google signin and using the Google php client library to authenticate to an API.

Comment: @DaImTo Thank you for your help on Stack Overflow, but i´ve already asked a few questions and they all turned out good. I´m completely new in the Google API and Stuff, so i don´t know what that difference is. That tutorial guy set up a google+ api and let it connect over some php-files on his webpage to it - The code is used to access and store data such as email adress, name and gender in a database. For more information about what code he used, just watch his video linked more up. I still haven´t found a solution.I´m happy about every useful response on how to replace his image with a button

Comment: @DaImTo Oh, if you´d like the tutorial (with all the code!) in text format, [here´s a link to it](https://www.codexworld.com/login-with-google-api-using-php/).

Comment: Please include the code that **YOU** are using that is problematic.

Comment: @JNYRanger I´ve got no problematic code. As long as following the tutorial, everything is fine. But i would like to know how to replace the picture he used for clicking on with a g-signin2-button.

Comment: Post the code that you are using.  You're opening a second useless window...I'd say that's problematic.

Comment: You are getting two becouse you are using to.  first JavaScript signin second php.  Why not pick one.

Comment: @DaImTo Yes, i know. I would like to only open the one through php. How can i prevent the second window (JavaScript, as you say) from opening. I do not want to replace the button with something else. Is there a way to do that? That was actually the point of my question...

Comment: Still waiting for some useful answers!